# 2000 Honda Accord misfires only some of the time. What is causing this?

Tags: honda, accord, misfire

It has a very odd pattern for when it misfires.
You start it at the beginning of the day and it works perfectly. You drive it around, turn it off, let it sit for 30 minutes, start it again, and you get a misfire on cylinder 4.

BUT

If you let it sit for less than 10 minutes, it starts again fine.
If you let it sit for more than 50 minutes, it starts again fine.

> less than 10 min = fine

> 10-50 min = misfire on cylinder 4

> more than 50 min = fine

What I've tried:
-Changing spark plug in cylinder 4
-Replacing distributor cap
-Changing all spark plug wires

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but if your scan tool is capable, have a look at the intake air temperature and see if the readings are plausible on cold start, just before shutdown after a drive, after letting sit for 30 minutes and after letting sit for more than 50 minutes.

Comment: You can usually find what @MTA is asking about under "Live Data" if your scanner supports it. Also, which engine does your Accord have in it?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the irregularities, you should stick to the correct sequence of diagnosing. You've practically done a tune up, so you might as well change the other spark plugs and rotor. Then you've pretty much eliminated spark, fuel and timing as a problem. So next try a wet and dry compression test or a leak down test. If they turn out ok, then I'd say it's then getting a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

Fuel Injectors may be the cause. Fuel Injectors must have a precise pressure and precise spray. This precise spray you should be getting may or may not be related to the pressure coming in because the sprayer itself may be intermittently clogged for reasons unknown. In short, Look up how to 'pressure test fuel injectors' for a vehicle of you make/model/year.

1. Fuel Injectors that need cleaning are symptomatic to misfiring.   https://www.autozone.com/diy/fuel-systems/the-symptoms-of-bad-fuel-injectors-and-what-to-do-about-it
2. If you do not know offhand what that pressure test all 4 cylinders and see if one of them is different. Look up how to pressure test a fuel injector for your car or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the [ignition control module](https://www.oreillyauto.com/shop/b/ignition---tune-up/ignition-module-control-unit-ignitor/9331d0e7f826/v/a/5983/automotive-car-2000-honda-accord) (ICM), which is sensitive to heat.  This part is responsible for simultaneously releasing the charge in an ignition coil and activating fuel injectors.  I replaced it on my car and immediately idle improved and gas mileage increased dramatically.